# Is it true that a flower can become stressed?

Tags: plant-health, wilt

I am reading a book and author said that if a go a nursery and find a flower that is yellowed or wilted it is probably not sick it can be "STRESSED". I thought this term very awkward. For me it can be a lack of sun or too much sun or lack of nutrients that caused the wilting. But he used the term "stressed". If it is true what can make a plant stressed?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Plants can be stressed, it means that they are not grown under perfect conditions. There are many types of stress, a distinction can be made between biotic and abiotic stress. Biotic stress is from other organisms, such as an infection or infestation of pests. Abiotic stress can be temperature, or lack of nutrients, or even light intensity (too low or too high).

Comment: Can the wind itself cause a flower to be stressed? I mean disconsidering if the wind is splashing onto the flower or carring away nutrients, only the "impact" of the wind.

Comment: Well, I know draft can give stress to indoor plants. Some plants become more susceptible to pests like spidermites when put in draft.

Comment: The folk at garden centers tend to miss a few trays when they water a zillion plants every day in the spring. That or strong sun or winds can stress a flower. If it's not too bad, a good watering will perk them right back up.